# Writing an adjacency matrix for a graph

Tags: matlab

I have imported two shapefiles to matlab, a polyline and a point one.
These are the city roads network.
The point shp has 9520 points and the line shp has 10444 lines(curves and...).
The point shp has coordinates of points and the the line shp has the coordinates of  the start and the end of the each line and length of each one.
I need to have an adjacency matrix (9520*9520) which has '1' elements for a direct relationship and '0' elements otherwise.

Comment: what have you done so far? post that as well as a small sample input and output dataset

Comment: C'mon.  Make some effort and actually do a search before actually posting a question.  It makes our lives and your's easier.